# Firefox gives me dbus error

Tags: firefox, d-bus

When I run Firefox under Wayland I get,

```
dbus[913]: arguments to dbus_message_new_method_call() were incorrect, assertion "_dbus_check_is_valid_path (path)" failed in file ../../../dbus/dbus-message.c line 1366.
This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.

  D-Bus not built with -rdynamic so unable to print a backtrace
Redirecting call to abort() to mozalloc_abort

ExceptionHandler::GenerateDump cloned child 925
ExceptionHandler::SendContinueSignalToChild sent continue signal to child
ExceptionHandler::WaitForContinueSignal waiting for continue signal...
```

I'm using Debian Bullseye. [I've tried setting `MOZ_DBUS_REMOTE=1` as per the Sway FAQ, but it didn't have any effect.](https://github.com/swaywm/sway/wiki#i-cant-open-links-in-external-applications-in-firefox) How can I get Firefox working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is a bug with Firefox's implementation of DBUS or Debian's packaging of Firefox,

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1555308

You can get around this by adding the `--no-remote` option.